# Remote debug Azure web job with .NET 6 in Visual Studio 2022

Tags: azure, visual-studio, azure-web-app-service, remote-debugging, azure-webjobs

I followed this tutorial to create a simple web job in Azure: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/webjobs-sdk-get-started. The web job itself does its job, consumes the message in the queue and I see them appear in Application Insights.
However, I want to debug the function on my local machine by using the tools available in Visual Studio 2022.

I have published with following profile settings:

[image: Profile settings]

Next I've attached the debugger under het Hosting menu:

[image: Attaching debugger]

First thing I noticed is a message about no symbols being loaded when putting a breakpoint in the function:

[image: No symbols have been loaded for this document]

When I add a message to my queue, it gets consumed by the web job but the breakpoint is never hit. I've been reading a lot of similar questions regarding a this issue but I'm not progressing any further.

- In Azure Portal, I've enabled Remote debugging under Configuration > general settings
  [image: Enable remote debugging in Azure Portal]
- In Visual Studio 2022, I checked if the correct process is attached
  [image: Attached processes in Visual Studio 2022]
  Here I'm a bit confused thou, the connection target is connecting through port 4024, which is according to [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/remote-debugger-port-assignments?view=vs-2022), the port for Visual Studio 2019. However, a connection target with port 4026 is not found.

**What am I missing here?** Am I forgetting another setting somewhere?

If have tried changing the stack setting .NET version from APS.NET V4.8 to NET 6 (LTS) but that didn't help.

[image: stack settings]

Should the platform architecture match the architecture of my machine in order to get it to work? Or is this not linked in any way with the debugger?

[image: platform architecture]

Is there anything else that I should check or try? Because my hair is turning grey here :)

Answer (score 0):

Apologies for the delay here!

It should be 4024 for both 32 and 64 bit.
See this Azure doc: [Remote Debugger Ports on Microsoft Azure App Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/debugger/remote-debugger-port-assignments?view=vs-2022#remote-debugger-ports-on-microsoft-azure-app-service)

Typically, the error *“The breakpoint will not currently be hit. No symbols have been loaded for this document.”* -- This error message indicates we can start debug process and attach, but cannot set a breakpoint on any or some lines of code in the project.

Most, likely cause:  Application is built without debug symbols or debug symbols are not available

Kindly try these steps:

- Verify Debug Symbols are being used and published and in sync
- Workaround the issue by disabling “Enable Just My Code” from the
  Tools >> Options >> Debugging >> general menu in Visual Studio

Other things to narrow-down the issue:

- Debug symbols must be available locally or deployed to the Azure App Service, and **must match the local code** you are trying to debug.
- It is recommended to use Cloud Explorer over Server Explorer to
  connect and debug which requires the Azure SDK.
- You could optionally [Manually Attach a Debugger to Azure Web Apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/archive/blogs/jpsanders/manually-attach-a-debugger-to-azure-web-apps) to troubleshoot this further or recommend this as a workaround.
  (old blog, try similar steps)
- Kindly verify the port (Visual Studio remote debugger port assignments ) required is open in the corporate firewall and on your local machine.
  As a test, you may use tool like Wireshark/netmon, to see if the port successfully connects to the port (4024) needed by the process.

Comment: There is no "Cloud Explorer" in VS 2022.